# How to make plugin enabled only at specific projects

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have several active projects. And only two of these need a Gerrit plugin. 
Is there any way to enable the plugin for a specific project?
It's very annoying to view on *access to gerrit* progress bar and error notifications about a *connection to the Gerrit failed* while I am working on another project.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-183.5429.30, built on January 29, 2019
```

Comment: It is not possible to do this for an arbitrary plugin. You need to file an issue for the Gerrit plugin requesting to add an option to enable it only for specific projects.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. I've found an issue in Gerrit issue tracker - https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-intellij-plugin/issues/159